# Localize Prism 4 Modules with .resx files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, prism

I'm working on a modularised Prism application. After some localized WPF clients with resx files (localized.resx, localized.de.resx etc.), i thought i could adapt this technique to my prism modules. But the module always takes the default resx.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use https://github.com/Jinjinov/wpf-localization-multiple-resource-resx-one-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that my ResourceManager has the wrong values in it's ResourceSet for the specific language. See my [New Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926047/wpf-resourcemanagers-resourceset-has-wrong-values)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it's not easy to explain this with a short message. So I wrote a really simple prism project with a working solution.

Try to download this [example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3993093/LocalizationExample.zip)

Comment: Hello pluka. Thanks for your solution. It took me just a short time to understand what you did. But after trying to adapt it to my existing project, i've ran into the same behaviour. The ResourceManager always chooses the default culture resource. After modifying your project, it doesn't uses your LocalizationHelper anymore, it still works. I changed the binding to <TextBlock Text="{x:Static res:Resource.textModule}"/> and it shows me the right localized resource. I'm really confused :|

Comment: Can you send me a little example of your code, I'll check it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Actually its pretty easy, just make sure to force your localization inside CreateShell() inside app.xaml.cs like this:

```
protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            SetLocalization();
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }
```

the SetLocalization() method can be like this :

```
private void LoadLocalizationFromSettings()
{
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
            
            //set pc default localization to be used in the XAML gui
            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                     typeof(FrameworkElement),
                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("en-us")));
}
```