# Resourcemanagers resourceset has wrong values

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, resx, resourcemanager

i'm developing a wpf / prism 4 application which uses localized resx resourcefiles. After some debugging (it didn't work as expected) i saw that all the resourceset's of my resourcemanager had the same values. The values of the default loc.resx.

[image]

[image]

My Question is: What's going wrong there?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally found the solution by myself. The problem was, that i xcopy my module dll to $(SolutionDir)\Modules to perform a directory discovery. But the Modul.resources.dll were not copied. I've copied them manually to $(SolutionDir)/Modules/en-GB/Modul.resources.dll and tadaaa it works :)

Comment: Great!! Thanks my dear!!